# Why are stats in Angband written as 18/** instead of 19, 20...?

Tags: angband

In Angband (and a lot of derivative, and maybe in its predecessors also), when your stats (e.g. DEX) is below 18, it is written with a single number (1 to 18), and after that, if the stat still increases, it is written with the following format: "18/xx", where xx goes from 10 to (more than) 200.

Also, xx increases by more than 1 when you get a +1 item.

What is the intuition behind this notation?

Comment: A similar convention is also adhered to by NetHack, which I assume inherited it from Hack and Rogue. (NetHack is at best a distant cousin of Angband.) Interestingly, NetHack also provides enchanted objects which set STR to a flat value of 25 (and  do not stack with anything else).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I can only give you a sort of meta-answer, where this system comes from, as I haven't played Angband.

Angbands attribute system is based on AD&D. In AD&D, strength (and only strength) could be represented with 18/xx numbers. 18 is supposed to be the maximum you can achieve without magic means in AD&D (also by virtue of it being the maximum roll on a 3d6), but Gary Gygax wanted to differentiate warriors more, so when a fighter(or paladin or ranger) reaches 18 strength, they get to roll a percentile die (d100) to get a percentile modifier to their strength, e.g. 18/50, or 18/90, where the latter is better than the former and 18/00 (meaning 18/100) would be the strongest person in the world.

This model provided a lot of problems, for example, the gap between 18 and 19 str is huge and if you ever got something, which boosted your strength, you get massively more powerful and this also allows non-fighter classes to leapfrog over fighters (non-fighters never got percentile, so if another class got a magic item boosting strength by 2 they'd go from 17 to 19, while a fighter would only go from 17 to 18/50).

The system was abandoned in D&D 3rd edition, but it still exists today in the Hackmaster RPG, which adds percentiles for every attributes and at every value (so you can be 12/45 or 14/13).

Angband seems to have embraced the concept that 18 is the maximum and cannot be improved upon and decided to go with percentiles at the top all the way. A +1 item improves it by more than 1 percentile, because a +1 is one full attribute point, while one percentile is not.

Comment: To extend this answer: Why 18? That's because this is the maximum of 3 six-sided dice. In (A)D&D, character stats are rolled up using 3d6 (or 4d6 and ignoring the lowest). Ability scores therefore range from 3 to 18.

Comment: @dulkan Its exactly what you said. [Every stat has a numerical value, ranging from a minimum of 3, up to a normal maximum of 18, and even higher, into the "percentile" range, represented as '18/01' through '18/100': this is the maximum that can be achieved intrinsically, for any given stat. These stats can be modified further by equipment, race and class bonuses up to a maximum of '18/220'.](https://rephial.org/help/birth)

Comment: Also, as @steenbergh mentioned, it confirms that it uses a concept of 3d6, since the minimum is 3, and not 1.

Comment: @Moacir Alternatively, use 1d16 and add 2. But yeah, 3d6 was the original.

Comment: @Delioth that would result in a very different distribution compared to 3d6, even if it has the same range.

Comment: @Chieron Oh yeah, I was just being cheeky

Comment: Also worth noting that in D&D only fighters got percentile strength. If you were a fighter with 17 strength and you got magic that gave you a +2 strength, it went to 18/10 (because every 10 percentage points was deemed equivalent to a +1), but a wizard would go to 19 strength and be much stronger for no real reason. It was really a poorly-thought out idea that was rightly dropped in 3rd edition never to be seen again.